# Django cannot find fandjango template (the application is installed)

Tags: django

I'm a n00b at openshift and I'm having an issue with a Django project.

I have these applications installed:

```
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'fandjango',
'schedule', #nuestras app particulares
'accounts'
```

Being `schedule` and `accounts` custom apps.

I migrated this (whole project, I mean) from an existing and working openshift hosting. When I installed every requirement (including, again, fandjango), everything worked but the essential: a not-found template (already installed it's app and don't know what's going on), in its corresponding exception.

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /fbapp/
fandjango/facebook_init.html
```

AND if I check the postmortem:

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
    Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
        /var/lib/openshift/5397226f5004467c0a00044d/app-root/runtime/repo/mundial2014/templates/fandjango/facebook_init.html (File does not exist)
    Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
        /var/lib/openshift/5397226f5004467c0a00044d/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/templates/fandjango/facebook_init.html (File does not exist)
        /var/lib/openshift/5397226f5004467c0a00044d/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/auth/templates/fandjango/facebook_init.html (File does not exist)
        /var/lib/openshift/5397226f5004467c0a00044d/app-root/runtime/repo/schedule/templates/fandjango/facebook_init.html (File does not exist)
        /var/lib/openshift/5397226f5004467c0a00044d/app-root/runtime/repo/accounts/templates/fandjango/facebook_init.html (File does not exist)
```

My question is: Why is not -the app_directories loader- traversing the file? If I open a python console and try `import fandjango` it works (i.e. `print fandjango`) outputs the module representation.

The setup for template loaders is the default for django 1.6 (filesystem and app directories) and my template dirs settings is:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'mundial2014', 'templates'),)
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it. Somehow installing by:

```
python setup.py install
```

Does not create the directory ([...])/site-packages/fandjango but only leaves the .egg file. So I had to `pip uninstall fandjango` and then `pip install fandjango` to have it properly installed as for django apps (it created the directory this time).